# Deleting nested object after time - MongoDB + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, timeout

I found information about MongoDB's TTL, which unfortunately only works on whole documents. I want to be able to delete user's notifications after some time (2 weeks) on my Node.js server. As you can imagine, the notifications are an array of objects as a field in the user's `MongoDB Model`, so that I can get them on login without further requests. So if I have something like this:

```
notifications: [{
        notifType: String,
        story: String,
        seen: Boolean,
        createdTime: Date,
        from: {
            name: String,
            username: String,
            id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
        }
    }]
```

How do I delete a notification after 2 weeks, counting from createdTime?

Comment: TTL indexes delete whole documents, so you'll need to find users with a notification > 2 weeks old and then scan their array for all notifications > 2 weeks and `$pull` all the old notifications. Or you can have a separate `notifications` collection and use TTL indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If culling them in a periodic batch process is not feasible, I would make the check as part of whatever code gets the document. You may have notifications longer than two weeks in the database, but assuming you have a single place where a 'get' takes place, you could do the check there and guarantee that no document with a stale notification is returned untrimmed.

Comment: I will accept your answer if no better one shows up. Otherwise, the notifications are part of the users model, in order not to make any request for them and get them on login. It will be quite messy to make such checks on login I guess.

Answer (score 0):

how does the default TTL implementation not do what you are expecting? 
Say your `createdTime` field has `2015-02-22:10:20` as the value and using the TTL feature you can

```
db.notifications.ensureIndex( { "createdTime": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

this will clear the value after 2 hours, Similarly you can set it to be 2 weeks. 
Unless your requirement is that each record has a different expiry for notifications the default implementation should do perfectly.

You could also write some code as part of the solution which deletes the records periodically, say at the beginning of each day or at the insertion of each record (the latter is not recommended).

Comment: It doesn't do what I want, because the notification is part of the users collection and I really don't want to delete the whole user. I am searching for a solution, which only deletes one object out of the notifications array in the user's model.

How do I write such code, that activates at a DateTime value, on Node.js?